# Python visualising 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I am looking to visualize some 3D `numpy` arrays in a similar manner I would do it with `pyplot.imshow` with 2D array.

It looks like the best option would be to use the `mayavi` package. Unfortunately, I am restricted to a RHEL system with fixed system-wide python and I cannot modify this version or add any packages to it. I managed to install a Python version over which I have more control via `virtualenv` and was quite happy with it until now, however this has put the installation of `vtk` and `wxPython` required for `mayavi` beyond my level of competence.

Is there a different way to perform such a visualization, even in a crude way? Alternatively, what is needed to make `wxPython` and `vtk` work with `virtualenv`?

Comment: If you want Mayavi, you might try using the Anaconda Python distribution which includes it, and would allow you to side step virtualenv and the system python in favor of conda: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in *slicing* your 3D `np.ndarray` and looking at cuts of the volume along the 3 axes, then a *very* simple tool, based on matplotlib, is [PyNax](https://github.com/AlexandreAbraham/pynax).

It allows you to visualize 3 orthogonal cuts of your data (along the three array axes) with interactive navigation through these cuts.